# Open Notes.app notes in an external editor

Tags: notes.app

I'd like to be able to search for words within the notes that I write in Notes.app. Since the search bar only narrows the list of notes, and doesn't actually highlight the word, I'd like to be able to open the notes in an external editor to perform searches.

Are the notes in for Notes.app located on the filesystem somewhere such that I can open them in an external editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search for some local notes with Spotlight or Alfred, the results will contain files like `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/CoreData/ExternalRecords/*/IMAPNote/_records/0/p8.notesexternalrecord`. Opening them opens the notes in Notes.app, but they're just empty property lists.

The contents of local notes are stored in a binary format in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/NotesV1.storedata`.

I don't know if there are any other applications that can edit or import the notes, but there's no rtfd files for them or anything.